# How can I have 2 textviews on the same line and at opposite ends of the screen at the same time

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I'm currently working on an app to display two text views at opposite ends of the screen.

This is the expected output:
[image: expected output]

This does work on some devices but on others it creates a new line and messes things up entirely or just removes the 22 entirely like this:
[image: unexpected output]

This is the xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="start">

    <TextView
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="James Lingard" />

    <TextView
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginStart="410dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="22" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The name on the left is great but the number on the right keeps getting messed up. I assume it has something to with `android:layout_marginStart="410dp"` but I'm not sure how else I can get the 22 to be on the right and on the same line as the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, with RelativeLayout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="James Lingard" />

<TextView
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" 
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="22" />
```

or I recomanded(is most adaptable) (P.S. Sorry for my english)

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="James Lingard" />

<TextView
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" 
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="22" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're right the problem is : `android:layout_marginStart="410dp"`.
I can suppose that on some devices the device screen width less than `410dp`.
As I can see you're using `RelativeLayout`, just add the attribute: `android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"` inside your 2nd `TextView`.

And, of course, remove this line: `android:layout_marginStart="410dp"`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `ConstraintLayout`

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="James Lingard"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:text="22"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Results

[image: Display two text]